# map.events.register() doesn't work on upper layer

Tags: openlayers, google-street-view

The code is the following:

```
map.events.register("click", map , activateGoogleStreetView).
```

It activates Google Street View when clicking on the map.
But when I have the upper layer, it doesn't work when I click on map.

[image: google street view example]

What is the way to get past this roadblock?
I tried managing it with z-index. To change the arrange of the map, but it doesn't work.